Monaco Editor for React doesn't recognize getValue function
Any idea why getValue() is not recognized?
const [value, setValue] = useState("");
const editorRef = useRef(null);

function handleUpdate() {
    if (editorRef.current) {
      const content = editorRef.current.getValue();
      setValue(content);
    }
  }


Property 'getValue' does not exist on type 'never'


This is the fix,
const editorRef = useRef([] as any);

